# The property 'ContentTypesEnabled' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set

Tags: powershell

I am trying to add content type to a list and the following code has worked in the past. This time it is giving me this error:

> The property 'ContentTypesEnabled' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.

Any idea why? Thank you.

```
$site = Get-SPSite $url

$rootWeb = $site.RootWeb
$ct = $rootWeb.ContentTypes["Project status"]
Write-Host "Content type:  " $ct.Name -ForegroundColor Green
$webs = $site.AllWebs;

foreach ($web in $webs) 
{
    Write-host $web.ServerRelativeUrl

    $list = $web.Lists[$listName]
    Write-Host "  List Name:" $list.Title -ForegroundColor Yellow

    $list.ContentTypesEnabled=$true
    $list.Update();
    $list.ContentTypes.Add($ct)
    $list.Update()
}
```

Comment: Do you see the list name printed to the console? If not, check if $listName is set correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to declaire your variable $list as SPList object, like this:

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList] $list = $web.Lists["NameOfTheList"]
```

If that does not work try to loop through your lists, something like this:

```
foreach($list in $web.Lists)
{
    if($list.Title -contains "YourListName")
    {
        $list.ContentTypesEnabled = $true
        $list.Update()
    }
}
```